# What service principle does Azure DevOps pipeline jobs run under?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-keyvault

I have a Azure DevOps pipeline that has a integration test task.  When the task runs the test needs access to a particular Azure KeyVault.  I need to give the principle under which the job is running in DevOps access to the KeyVault.  However, I'm a little confused which principle the job is running under.

I tried the following, however it did not make any difference:

In the Azure DevOps website I went to: Project Settings -> Service Connections -> Manage service principle.  This then loads a page in the Azure portal for the principle. I've taken that principle and granted them read access in the KeyVaut service, however the test is still failing with the same error.

Is there another principle that is actually running the job (i.e. I'm looking in the wrong place) or is there something else I haven't thought of?

For reference this is the error I get back (I replaced the GUID for security reasons):

```
Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProviderException : Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority: https://login.windows.net/<SOME_GUID>. Exception Message: Tried the following 3 methods to get an access token, but none of them worked.
Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority: https://login.windows.net/<SOME_GUID>. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Managed Service Identity. Access token could not be acquired. Received a non-retryable error. MSI ResponseCode: BadRequest, Response: {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Identity not found"}
Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority: https://login.windows.net/<SOME_GUID>. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Visual Studio. Access token could not be acquired. Environment variable LOCALAPPDATA not set.
Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority: https://login.windows.net/<SOME_GUID>. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Azure CLI. Access token could not be acquired. Please run 'az login' to setup account.
```

Comment: what kind of task are you running for the test? Is it Visual Studio Test?

Comment: @Nilay DotNetCoreCLI@2 (dotnet test). I'm running it from an azure-pipelines.yml file.

Comment: To me it looks like the code is asking for it? Did you write the tests? Have you tried running them locally?

Comment: Locally yes. They run fine. I have obviously given myself access to KV.

Comment: Ok Cool. Are you running from VS? Is your code using Managed Identity?

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check out below solutions, how did it go?

Answer (score 4):

The test code cannot access to the service connection you created, if the service connection is not associated to your pipeline within the tasks.

1,As workaround you can try executing your test using commands in [Azure Cli task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops). See below: Set the `azureSubscription` to the service connection you created. Azure Cli task will connect to your azure subscription using the authentication in the service connection. And the test will run in the current context of azure cli.  See [Authenticating with Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/service-to-service-authentication#authenticating-with-azure-cli) for more information.

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: Azure CLI
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: <Name of the Azure service connection>
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    scriptType: pscore
    inlineScript: |
      dotnet test
```

2,You can also [Use a shared secret credential to sign into Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/service-to-service-authentication#use-a-shared-secret-credential-to-sign-into-azure-ad). Refer to below steps:

> Provide a `connectionString` to `AzureServiceTokenProvider` constructor as below:

`var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider("connectionString=#{keyVaultEndpoint}#;RunAs=App;AppId=#{appId}#;TenantId=#{tenantId}#;AppKey=#{clientSecret}#")`

> Define `keyVaultEndpoint`,`appId`,`tenantId`,`clientSecret` variables in your pipeline.
>
> Add [replace token task](https://github.com/qetza/vsts-replacetokens-task#readme) to replace below {AppId}, {TenantId}, and {ClientSecret} in the `connectionString` with the variables' value in the pipeline.

[image]

3,You can also try creating a [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) on your local machine. And run your pipeline against this oself-hosted agent. Since the tests run fine locally, it should be fine too on the self-hosted agent on your local machine.

Hope above helps!

Comment: Thanks for this comment, option 1 helped me, even though I had to do a lot of changes (and not just adding the task as mentioned) for it to work.

Comment: Here's something that might save others some time. If you're using DefaultAzureCredential, which a lot of projects and tools do, note the order of precedence used to select the credentials. I was scratching my head after a pipeline kept using build agent credentials over the service connection credentials. It's because the build agent had a managed identity and this had higher precedence than the AzureCliCredential of the service connection.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet