# How can I login azure on PowerShell that run on Azure DevOps

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-keyvault

I have a PowerShell file which is use for getting the secret value from one of our Azure Key Vault for later use (login to Power BI with Service Principal). Here is the screenshot from DevOps,

[image]

And here is my PS code,

```
Write-Output "Get Secret from AKV"
$secret = az keyvault secret show --vault-name PA01 --name <my key vault secret name> --output json
$x = $secret | ConvertFrom-Json

$azureAplicationId = "<my client id>"
$azureTenantId= "<my tenant id>"

Write-Output "Generate Credential"
$azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $x.value -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureAplicationId , $azurePassword)

Write-Output "Login SP"
Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -Tenant $azureTenantId -ServicePrincipal -Credential $psCred
```

I can run it successfully on Cloud shell, while it fails on my Azure DevOps pipeline. As you can see the screenshot below,

[image]

I think the job failed when running this command:

```
$secret = az keyvault secret show --vault-name PA01 --name <my key vault secret name> --output json
```

Because although the job has automatic running the **Connect-AzAccount** command, the login is invalid, and on my understand that is why it say "Error: Please run az login to setup account" (guess so), so the "az keyvault" command cannot be run.

Yes, I can add "az login --use-device-code" on my script and it run successful by enter code manually, **but the problem is**,

**I don't want any interactive experience in the login process, because I hope this job is fully automatic and unattended.**

So, any solution for this?  Deeply grateful for you help!

Answer (score 0):

Please check these:

PowerShell script works only with Windows agent, make sure the agent has PowerShell version 5 or lower.

Workaround

- Try setup a Self hosted agent on your machine(connected to the
  internet).
- Then you can run the task on a self hosted agent, and choose to run a
  powershell task. (This may require you  you to whitelist some devops
  ranges on your firewall).

(Or)

As usually [Azure Cli Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops) will authenticate using [az login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest). As a work around try to use Az CLI task  and azureSubscription with service connection name.
This includes authentication against an azure subscription as part of its setup, so you will be able to run az cli commands.

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: Azure CLI
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: <Name of the Azure Resource service connection>
    scriptType: ps
    .....
```

Here Also check if service connection used in the pipeline has **sufficient permissions** to run the script.For that ensure the service principle/ authentication credentials have the [required permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-powershell?view=azure-devops#script-worked-locally-but-failed-in-the-pipeline).

Try to downgrade /upgrade the version of azure-cli on the Hosted Agent Pool to near 2.0.64 or Use Hosted VS2017 agent to run az commands

See [Azure PowerShell task - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-powershell?view=azure-devops)

**References:**

1. [What service principle does Azure DevOps pipeline jobs run under? -
   Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61929357/what-service-principle-does-azure-devops-pipeline-jobs-run-under)
2. [az login fails wih Azure DevOps Pipelines - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54513537/az-login-fails-wih-azure-devops-pipelines/54546350#54546350)
3. [Use Azure CLI within Azure Powershell Task - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52923927/use-azure-cli-within-azure-powershell-task)

Answer (score 0):

Use PowerShell command instead of the `az` command to get the secret.

```
$secret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName 'MyKeyVaultName' -Name 'MySecretName'
$secretValue = $secret.SecretValueText
```

Make sure the service connection that is configured at `azureSubscription:` is added to the Access Policies section of the Key vault as the command is executed in that context.